# Read and Write configuration settings managment in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose in MongoDB there are multiple DBs(DB1, DB2, ... DBa, DBb, ....) and each of them has some collections(Col1A, Col1B, ... Col2A, Col2B, ...)

I want to find a way to manage multiple inputs and outputs in MongoDB. I want to have a **self-contained** Scala Application written in the Scala language. Here is pseudocode that shows my idea:

```
readconfig_DB1.Col1A=Read setting pointing to DB=DB1 and collection=Col1A
readconfig_DB2.Col2B=Read setting pointing to DB=DB2 and collection=Col2B

val rdd_DB1.Col1A = MongoSpark.load(sc_DB1.Col1A)
val rdd_DB2.Col2B = MongoSpark.load(sc_DB2.Col2B)

DF_Transofmration1 = Do some transformations on DF1a and DF2b
DF_Transofmration2 = Do some transformations on DF1b and DF2a

writeConfig_DBa.Col1A=Write setting pointing to DB=DB1 and collection=Col1A
writeConfig_DBb.Col2B=Write setting pointing to DB=DB2 and collection=Col2B

MongoSpark.save(DF_Transofmration1 , writeConfig_DBa.Col1A)
MongoSpark.save(DF_Transofmration2 , writeConfig_DBa.Col2B)
```

---

**Edit1**:

I tried to run the solution.

The structure of folders:

```
$find .
.
./src
./src/main
./src/main/scala
./src/main/scala/application.conf
./src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala
./build.sbt
```

Content of `build.sbt`

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "2.4.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.1"
)
```

Content of `application.conf`:

```
config{
    database {
      "spark_mongodb_input_uri": "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection",
      "spark_mongodb_user":"",
      "spark_mongodb_pass":"",
      "spark_mongodb_input_database": "test",
      "spark_mongodb_input_collection": "myCollection",
      "spark_mongodb_input_readPreference_name": "",
      "spark_mongodb_output_database": "test",
      "spark_mongodb_output_collection": "myCollection"
    }

    newreaderone {
      "database": "test",
      "collection": "myCollection",
      "readPreference.name": ""
    }

    newwriterone {
      "uri":"mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection"
      "database": "test",
      "collection": "myCollection",
      "replaceDocument": "false",//If set to True, updates an existing document
      "readPreference.name": "",
      "maxBatchSize": "128"
    }
}
```

content of `SimpleApp.scala`:

```
import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
import com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object FirstApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    import com.typesafe.{Config,ConfigFactory}
    val appConfig: Config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    val initial_conf:Config = appconf.getConfig("config.database")
    val confMap: Map[String,String] = initial_conf.entrySet()
    .iterator.asScala
    .map(e => e.getKey.replaceAll("_",".") -> e.getValue.unwrapped.toString).toMap
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame,SparkSession}
    val sparkConfig: SparkConf=new SparkConf()
    sparkConfig.setAll(confMap)
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config(sparkConf).enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate
    import com.mongodb.spark._
    val data: DataFrame = MongoSpark.load(spark)
    import com.mongodb.spark.config._
    val nreader = appConfig.getConfig("config.newreaderone")
    val readMap: Map[String,Any] = nreader.entrySet()
    .iterator.asScala
    .map(e => e.getKey -> e.getValue.unwrapped)
    .toMap
    val customReader = ReadConfig(readMap)
    val newDF: DataFrame = spark.read.mongo(customReader)
    resultDF.write.mode("append").mongo()

 }
}
```

Error after compilation:

```
sbt package
[info] Updated file /Path/3/project/build.properties: set sbt.version to 1.3.10
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/sadegh/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Path/3/project
[info] Loading settings for project root-3 from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to root-3 (in build file:/Path/3/)
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Path/3/target/scala-2.11/classes ...
[error] /Path/3/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:8:13: object typesafe is not a member of package com
[error]         import com.typesafe.{Config,ConfigFactory}
[error]                    ^
[error] /Path/3/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:9:17: not found: type Config
[error]         val appConfig: Config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
[error]                        ^
[error] /Path/3/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:9:26: not found: value ConfigFactory
[error]         val appConfig: Config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
[error]                                 ^
[error] /Path/3/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:11:19: not found: type Config
[error]         val initial_conf:Config = appconf.getConfig("config.database")
[error]                          ^
[error] /Path/3/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:11:28: not found: value appconf
[error]         val initial_conf:Config = appconf.getConfig("config.database")
[error]                                   ^
[error] /Path/3/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:19:56: not found: value sparkConf
[error]         val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config(sparkConf).enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate
[error]                                                               ^
[error] /Path/3/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:28:21: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
[error]   (options: scala.collection.Map[String,String])com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig.Self <and>
[error]   (sparkConf: org.apache.spark.SparkConf)com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig.Self <and>
[error]   (sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext)com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig.Self <and>
[error]   (sparkSession: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession)com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig.Self <and>
[error]   (sparkContext: org.apache.spark.SparkContext)com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig.Self
[error]  cannot be applied to (scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any])
[error]         val customReader = ReadConfig(readMap)
[error]                            ^
[error] /Path/3/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:29:36: value mongo is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader
[error]         val newDF: DataFrame = spark.read.mongo(customReader)
[error]                                           ^
[error] /Path/3/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:30:2: not found: value resultDF
[error]         resultDF.write.mode("append").mongo()
[error]         ^
[error] 9 errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 12 s, completed Jun 14, 2020 6:55:43 PM
```

Comment: Please let me know if the question is not clear/complete so I add missing elements.

Comment: where to read and write db configuration? properties file? or database?

Comment: I don't know the difference, I guess the properties file is the easier to start.

Comment: can you add more details like what kind of read & write settings, transformations.. or give some sample configs ??

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the configurations as inputs to your application in HOCON.
You can try the following HOCON configuration snippet for mulitple read and write configuration.

```
config{
    database {
      "spark_mongodb_input_uri": "mongodb://connection/string/here",
      "spark_mongodb_user":"your_user_name",
      "spark_mongodb_pass":"your_password",
      "spark_mongodb_input_database": "Some_Db_Name",
      "spark_mongodb_input_collection": "Some_Col_Name",
      "spark_mongodb_input_readPreference_name": "primaryPreferred",
      "spark_mongodb_output_database": "Some_Output_Db_Name",
      "spark_mongodb_output_collection": "Some_Output_Col_Name"
    }

    newreaderone {
      "database": "sf",
      "collection": "matchrecord",
      "readPreference.name": "secondaryPreferred"
    }

    newwriterone {
      "uri":"mongodb://uri of same or new mongo cluster/instance"
      "database": "db_name",
      "collection": "col_name",
      "replaceDocument": "false",//If set to True, updates an existing document
      "readPreference.name": "secondaryPreferred",
      "maxBatchSize": "128"
    }
}
```

the above configuration has been tested and can be read easily with Typesafe Config library.

Update:

Enter the above configuration in a file call **application.conf**.
Use the following line of code to read the file

Step 1:
Reading the configuration file

```
import com.typesafe.{Config,ConfigFactory}

val appConfig: Config = ConfigFactory.load("/path/to/application.conf")
```

Step 2:
To initialize spark to read and write to MongoDB we use the config under the **database** section as follows:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val initial_conf:Config = appconf.getConfig("config.database")

val confMap: Map[String,String] = initial_conf.entrySet()
.iterator.asScala
.map(e => e.getKey.replaceAll("_",".") -> e.getValue.unwrapped.toString).toMap
```

Step 3: Create SparkSession

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame,SparkSession}

val sparkConfig: SparkConf=new SparkConf()

sparkConfig.setAll(confMap)

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config(sparkConf).enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate
```

Step 4:
Read DataFrame from MongoDB

```
import com.mongodb.spark._
val data: DataFrame = MongoSpark.load(spark)
```

The above step reads the collection specified in the **database** section of the configuration

Step 5: 
Reading a new collection:

```
import com.mongodb.spark.config._

val nreader = appConfig.getConfig("config.newreaderone")

val readMap: Map[String,Any] = nreader.entrySet()
.iterator.asScala
.map(e => e.getKey -> e.getValue.unwrapped)
.toMap

val customReader = ReadConfig(readMap)

val newDF: DataFrame = spark.read.mongo(customReader)
```

Step 6:
Writing to MongoDB Collection

```
resultDF.write.mode("append").mongo()
```

Above code writes to the collection speified under the **database** section of the configuration

ii) Writing to collection other than the one specified in SparkConf

```
import com.mongodb.spark.config._


val nwriter = appConfig.getConfig("config.newwriterone")

val writerMap: Map[String,Any] = nreader.entrySet()
            .iterator.asScala
            .map(e => e.getKey -> e.getValue.unwrapped).toMap

val writeConf = WriteConfig(writerMap)

MongoSpark.save(resultDF, writeConf)
```

Update:

The whole code looks as folows, look at the two ways I save the dataframe into MongoDb in the end

```
import com.typesafe.{Config,ConfigFactory}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame,SparkSession}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import com.mongodb.spark._
import com.mongodb.spark.config._


object ReadWriteMongo{

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val appConfig: Config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")

    val initial_conf:Config = appconf.getConfig("config.database")

    val confMap: Map[String,String] = initial_conf.entrySet()
    .iterator.asScala
    .map(e => e.getKey.replaceAll("_",".") -> e.getValue.unwrapped.toString).toMap

    val sparkConfig: SparkConf=new SparkConf()

    sparkConfig.setAll(confMap)

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config(sparkConf).enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate

    val data: DataFrame = MongoSpark.load(spark)

    val nreader = appConfig.getConfig("config.newreaderone")

    val readMap: Map[String,Any] = nreader.entrySet()
    .iterator.asScala
    .map(e => e.getKey -> e.getValue.unwrapped)
    .toMap

    val customReader = ReadConfig(readMap)

    /*
    Read Data from MongoDB
    */
    val newDF: DataFrame = spark.read.mongo(customReader)


    /*
    * After you performing processing on the newDF above and save
    * the result in a new Dataframe called "resultDF". 
    * You can save the DF as follows
    */
    resultDF.write.mode("append").mongo()

    /*
    *Alternatively You can save a Dataframe also by passing a WriteConfig as follows
    */

    val nwriter = appConfig.getConfig("config.newwriterone")

    val writerMap: Map[String,Any] = nreader.entrySet()
                .iterator.asScala
                .map(e => e.getKey -> e.getValue.unwrapped).toMap

    val writeConf = WriteConfig(writerMap)

    MongoSpark.save(resultDF, writeConf)
  }
}
```

The folder structure should be as follows:

```
src/

src/main/scala/com/test/ReadWriteMongo.scala

src/main/resources/application.conf
```

Update: **build.sbt**

```
val sparkVersion = "2.4.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-deprecation",
  "-feature",
  "-Xfuture",
  "-encoding",
  "UTF-8",
  "-unchecked",
  "-language:postfixOps"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.4.0",
"org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Provided
)

mainClass in assembly := Some("com.test.SimpleApp.scala")

assembly / test := {}

assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value}-${version.value}.jar"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf")       => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.matches("meta-inf.*\\.sf$")   => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "reference.conf"                                 => MergeStrategy.concat
  case x: String if x.contains("UnusedStubClass.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case _                                                => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Comment: Can you please complete the code so that I can run it? I don't know how to use this snippet.

Comment: I made and edit to the solution describing the steps

Comment: For a detailed information you can follow the official documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/v2.3)

Comment: If this solution worked for you can you accept my answer?

Comment: I tried to run the solution but I received an error. pls take a look at the question. Once the solution is working, I will accept the answer and give you the bounty

Comment: I have updated my answer. the import statement had a period (".") after it. hence the error Also you need to put your configuration file in the resources folder. the path to resources folder is `src/main/resources/`

Comment: I think it will be much easier if you can run the code in your own environment creating the same folder structure as I did and  test it.

Comment: how are you running the Spark Job?

Comment: using `sbt package` and then with `spark-submit   --class "FirstApp"   --master local[4]   target/scala-2.11/root-2_2.11-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215974/discussion-between-yayati-sule-and-woeitg).

Comment: Hi Were you able to build the jar?

Comment: no, take a look at the error happened when building the jar file

Comment: hi, I have added the snippet to the build.sbt file. I have added the dependency for Typesafe Config

Comment: thanks, will take a look soon. theses days I am very busy